# How to add an account in Apple Mail without downloading older messages?

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail

I recently took on a position in an organization, and with it I gained access to the organization's e-mail account.  I would like to add the account to Apple Mail.  The organization has been around for a while, though, so there are thousands of e-mails in the inbox.  I want to download all future e-mails to the account, but not past e-mails.

How do you prevent Apple Mail from downloading old messages when adding an account?

I'm running OS X Lion, and the new inbox is on Gmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some strange answer for your strange question, but i'll post it.

In gmail account settings enable access via POP, and set it for mail that arrives from now.
Then set up Mail app and you'll get only new emails.

Comment: It's not a strange answer to a strange question, and it is a solution to the problem at hand.  For my case I'm okay with not having IMAP access, because I will still be using the Gmail mostly from the online interface.  Thanks!